# Removing Duplicate Lines by Title Only

Tags: python-2.7, text-files, duplicates

I am trying to modify a script so that it will remove duplicate lines from a text file using only the title portion of that line.

To clarify the text file lines look something like this:

```
Title|Image Url|Description|Page Url
```

At the moment the script does remove duplicates, but it does so by reading the entire line, not just the first part. All the lines in the file are not going to be 100% the same, but a few will be very similar.

I want to remove all of the lines that contain the same "title", regardless of what the rest of the line contains.

This is the script I am working with:

```
import sys
from collections import OrderedDict

infile = "testfile.txt"
outfile = "outfile.txt"
inf = open(infile,"r")
lines = inf.readlines()

inf.close()

newset = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(lines))
outf = open(outfile,"w")
lstline = len(newset)
for i in range(0,lstline):
   ln = newset[i]
   outf.write(ln)
outf.close()
```

So far I have tried using `.split()` to split the lines in the list. I have also tried `.readline(lines[0:25])` in hopes of using a character limit to achieve the desired results, but no luck so far. I also can't seem to find any documentation on my exact problem so I'm stuck.

I am using Windows 8 and Python 2.7.9 for this project if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a few changes to the program you had set up.  First, I changed your file interactions to use "with" statements, since those are very convenient and automatically handle a lot of the functionality you had to write out.  Second off, I used a `set` instead of an `OrderedDict` because you were basically just trying to emulate set functionality (exclusivity of elements) by using keys in an OrderedDict.  If the title hasn't been used, it adds it to the set so it can't be used again and prints the line to the output file.  If it has been used, it keeps going.  I hope this helps you!

```
with open("testfile.txt") as infile:
    with open("outfile.txt",'w') as outfile:
        titleset = set()

        for line in infile:
            title =  line.split('|')[0]
            if title not in titleset:
                titleset.add(title)
                outfile.write(line)
```